# MeanJS: Crud Module Failing Data Validation

Tags: node.js, validation, meanjs

I am using Mean.JS to create an application.

I'm working on trying to setup a CRUD module for one of my Models "Exchanges".

I am having an issue with data validation when adding a new Exchange through the interface.

I get back "Please fill in API key", even though in the form I have the attribute filled out:

In my model (exchange.server.model.js):

```
    var ExchangeSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill Exchange name',
            trim: true
        },
        apikey: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill in API Key',
            trim: true
        },
        secret: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill in Secret Key',
            trim: true
        }
        // ...
    });
```

In my view (create-exchange.client.view.html):

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>

        <label class="control-label" for="apikey">API Key</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="apikey" id="apikey" class="form-control" placeholder="API Key" required>
        </div>

        <label class="control-label" for="secret">Secret Key</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="secret" id="secret" class="form-control" placeholder="Secret Key" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in my server side controller (exchange.server.controller.js):

```
    exports.create = function(req, res) {
        var exchange = new Exchange(req.body);
        exchange.user = req.user;
        exchange.slug = req.body.name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '');

        exchange.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(exchange);
            }
        });
    };
```

**Any advice on why this is failing the validation and returning the 'required' string defined in my model file  would be much appreciated.**

**Update:**

In my server side controller (exchanges.server.controller.js) I added the following lines while debugging:

```
console.log("REQUEST: " + util.inspect(req.body) );
```

and I get the response:

```
 REQUEST: { name: 'SomeExchangeName' }
```

without the apikey/secretkey values being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out :)

In my clientside controller I needed to add the attributes to the Exchange object before it gets saved.

```
     $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Exchange object
        var exchange = new Exchanges ({
            name: this.name,
            apikey: this.apikey,   // THIS LINE HERE 
            secret: this.secret    // AND THIS LINE HERE
        });

        // Redirect after save
        exchange.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('exchanges/' + response._id);

            // Clear form fields
            $scope.name = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
```